# How to position text under two images

Tags: css

I have tried all sorts to find an answer to this, but what I want to do is have some text centered under two images.

I have tried using a  turned into a line, but I cannot get the text to be under the centre of the image. Can any one help me ?

The web page is www.c5d.co.uk/captain.php

The HTML is:

```
 <img class="social" src="http://www.c5d.co.uk/captain.png" alt="Captain">
 <img class="socialtwo" src="http://www.c5d.co.uk/president.png" alt="President">
 <div><ul class="captain"><li><p>John Lewis: Captain</p><p>Bill Wrigley: President</p>             </li></ul></div>
 <img class="social" src="http://www.c5d.co.uk/ladycaptain.png" alt="Lady Captain">
 <img class="socialtwo" src="http://www.c5d.co.uk/juniorcaptain.png" alt="Junior  Captain">
 <div><ul class="ladycaptain"><li><p>Beryl Harrison: Lady Captain</p><p>Kieran Metcalf: Junior Captain</p></li></ul></div>
```

The relevant CSS is

```
 .captain, .ladycaptain {                /* ul - controls normal comp results& junior open*/
list-style-type:none;
display:table;
padding:0;
margin:0 auto;
}
 .captain li, .ladycaptain li {
display:table-row;
text-align:left;/* ul - controls normal comp results& junior open*/
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
  .ladycaptain p  {
display:table-cell;/* ul - controls normal comp results & junior open*/
text-align:left;
padding:3px 10px 3px 0;  /* padding-right visually separates "columns" */
}




 .captain p  {
display:table-cell;/* ul - controls normal comp results & junior open*/
text-align:left;
padding:3px 10px 3px 0;  /* padding-right visually separates "columns" */
}

 .ladycaptain p  {
display:table-cell;/* ul - controls normal comp results & junior open*/
text-align:left;
padding:3px 20px 3px 0;  /* padding-right visually separates "columns" */
}



.captain p + p {
padding-left:225px;       /* padding-left visually separates "columns" */
}
.ladycaptain p + p {
padding-left:180px;       /* padding-left visually separates "columns" */
}
```

Comment: Try grouping the image and caption into a single container/div and centering the contents. It will be much easier to do if you can restructure the HTML.

Comment: Like @Rob Grzyb said : http://jsfiddle.net/KV7zT/

Comment: Like RobGrzyb and Pow-lan said : http://jsfiddle.net/KV7zT/1/

Answer (score 0):

Right now you have more HTML and CSS than you need, which is making your code harder to read and fix than it needs to be.  Putting the text for each image in their own `div` will make it easier to center them, and be closer semantically to what you're trying to achieve.  Then you can also use far less CSS to make it behave as you want.

Restructuring your HTML and CSS should do the trick:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#officers {
    width:554px;
}

.officer {
    width:267px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    margin:3px 10px 3px 0;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="officers">
    <div class="officer">
        <img src="http://www.c5d.co.uk/captain.png" alt="Captain" />
        <span class="caption">John Lewis: Captain</span>
    </div>
    <div class="officer">
        <img src="http://www.c5d.co.uk/president.png" alt="President" />
        <span class="caption">Bill Wrigley: President</span>
    </div>
    <div class="officer">
        <img src="http://www.c5d.co.uk/ladycaptain.png" alt="Lady Captain" />
        <span class="caption">Beryl Harrison: Lady Captain</span>
    </div>
    <div class="officer">
        <img src="http://www.c5d.co.uk/juniorcaptain.png" alt="Junior Captain" />
        <span class="caption">Kieran Metcalf: Junior Captain</span>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This has centred the text and the images but has had the effect of removing the tabs from the left hand side and putting them underneath.

Comment: All of the buttons down the left hand side of the page are sent to the bottom of the page

Comment: How this interacts with the buttons on the left side of the page will depend on the positioning and display properties of both the officers `div` and the sidebar `ul`.  I can't give a definitive answer since I can't see how you combined the code in my answer with your own.  But try giving your sidebar `ul` `position:relative;float:left;` and some appropriate margins - that may solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Suggested by @Rob Grzyb :

Try grouping the image and caption into a single container/div and centering the contents. It will be much easier to do if you can restructure the HTML.

Suggested by @Pow-Ian : jsfiddle.net/KV7zT

Edited by me : jsfiddle.net/KV7zT/1  or  [jsfiddle.net/KV7zT/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/KV7zT/2/)

html

```
<div style='text-align:center;width:50%;float:left;'>
    <img src="http://www.c5d.co.uk/president.png" alt="President" />
    <div style="clear:both"> Text Goes Here</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.none-needed {css:not needed 'yet';}
```

Comment: How does this work if there are four images, in two rows of two ?

The text isn't centred under the relevant image as far as I can see because you would need extra CSS to align the images together ?  Or am I missing something ?

Comment: Hi, well, copy-paste this block 4 times and it will render OK. See it here : http://jsfiddle.net/KV7zT/3/

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the margin-bottom of the images.
2. Increase the height of the ul containing the text.
3. Set the line-height of that li ( or a group of 'em ) to that height. It will be perfectly centered. Well of course it will be centered vertically, if that's what you want to achieve. Otherwise just setting the text-align to center should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img class="img1" src="" alt="">
        <div>image 1</div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <img class="img2" src="" alt="">
        <div>image 2</div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <img class="img3" src="" alt="">
        <div>image 3</div>
    </li>
    ....
</ul>
```

with css

```
li
{
  display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
}
div
{
 text-align: center;
}
```

Here's a [LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/8AdJN/1/)

Comment: This almost works.  It centers the text under the right hand images, but the left hand ones have the text at the right hand side. I have checked what I have done and it does seem correct. Would you be kind enough to look at c5d.co.uk/captain.php and see where I have gone awry ?

Comment: @Antony : Onyour img.social class (1) add a width for your image. Something like: width: 267px; and (2) [on the same class] replace your margin rules with this one: margin: 0 auto 25px auto;  .... do the same for theimg.socialtwo class

Comment: Did you mean to do this ? .officials li
{
  display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto 25px auto;
}

I have looked at this so long, am now on Day 2 !  I reached the stage of not seeing wood for trees. I ask only it has made n difference

Comment: @Antony No, wrong class. goto the img.social class and change it to: img.social {
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto 25px auto;
    width: 267px;
}

Comment: You also might have to do something similar to the img.socialtwo class... but first try it on the  img.social class

Comment: If I do that, then the two images align right next to other because the margin right is not on the left hand image. The text itself doesn't seem to move, it is the image moving that makes it look centred.  I'm afraid that I am off to work now so I cannot reply further today.  Just didn;t want you to think I was ignorin g you

Comment: @Antony on the  .officials li class add your left and right margins. like this:                                                    .officials li{ margin: 0 40px 25px 40px;

Comment: I did that and the images lined up vertically centred

Comment: then reduce the right/left margins according to what you need you may have to play with them to get them right. Try .officials li{ margin: 0 20px 25px 20px;

Answer (score 0):

I gave up ! and tried something different.

Just have a text spacing error now !

Thanks for all your suggestions

Antony